# How to ask a question of type "file upload"

Tags: r-exams, openolat

Using `exams2openolat` for exporting exercises from R/exams to OpenOlat, is there a way to ask a question where the student can upload a file as an answer (pdf, jpg, ...)? This would be useful for mathematical proofs for example which are just easier written by hand and then scanned rather than typed.

According to this tweet

> [...] The QTI engine in OpenOlat is very cool & powerful!
>
> We're trying to catch up with its interaction features (e.g.,
> matching, ordering) but some (e.g., file upload) have been added in
> #rexams devel. [...]
>
> https://twitter.com/achimzeileis/status/1333912916299485184

there should be such an option in the development version of R/exams, but I can not find anything else about that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the actual problem or question you're asking. If you remove the redundant tag information from your title, what remains is *File upload question*, which is meaningless. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title is not useful in that regard. Thanks.

Comment: Just changed the title, I hope you find it more suitable for the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Extended string items

Indeed, this feature is available in `exams2openolat` (and `exams2qti21` more generally; partially also in `exams2moodle`) starting from version 2.4-0. The simple idea is that you can set a "type" for `string` exercises and `string` elements in `cloze` exercises:

- `string`: This is the default type for a `string` exercise, leading to a small fill-in-the-blank field. This is scored automatically by exact string matching.
- `essay`: Alternatively, you can get a larger text field where students can enter longer answers. This has to be scored manually by the lecturer.
- `file`: As another alternative you can get a file upload interaction at the end of the exercise. Again this has to be scored manually by the lecturer.

#### Simple string example

A very basic example asking for a proof (as described in your question) is provided below. The `exstringtype` is set to `file` and hence no `exsolution` is needed (because it cannot be scored automatically) which is therefore set to `nil`. The exercise uses R/Markdown .Rmd markup - it would, of course, be also possible to use R/LaTeX .Rnw markup. Also you could include a `Solution` section if you wanted to.

```
Question
========
Under which assumptions is the ordinary least squares (OLS) estimator
for the coefficients in the linear regression model unbiased?
Outline the steps for the corresponding proof.

Please upload your solution as an image file (PDF, PNG, JPG, ...).

Meta-information
================
exname: Unbiasedness OLS
extype: string
exstringtype: file
exsolution: nil
```

#### More complex cloze example

Similarly, in a `cloze` exercise you could set the `exclozetype` to `essay` or `file` for a certain element. A worked example is available in the development version of the package as `lm3.Rmd` which combines all possible elements in a single cloze: `string`, `mchoice`, `num`, `schoice`, `essay`, `file`. Try: `exams2openolat("lm3.Rmd", ...)`. In OpenOlat the open-ended elements (`essay` and `file`) have to be scored by the lecturer while the remaining elements can be scored automatically as usual.